# Authentication firebase google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

If I use firebase authentication with google, how can I get the user names of those who have verified account with google to generate a table in an app?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Desafortunadamente, las preguntas y respuestas deben ser publicadas en inglés. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: It is recommended to post questions in English so that all users can help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database of users (using [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) database) and access them. When a new user signs up, add him to db.